# ColorPicker text input field truncates the value on paste

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

When pasting into a ColorPicker text field the color value is truncated sometimes.

For example, if I paste, `#0000FF` then the text field displays, `#0000F`.

If I close the color picker and then open it open again and paste again it shows `#0000FF`.

I started trying to fix it and then I found this code in the textInput change handler in the SwatchPanel class:

```
private function textInput_changeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    // Handle events from hex TextField.
    var color:String = ITextInput(event.target).text;
    if (color.charAt(0) == "#")
    {
        textInput.maxChars = 7;
        color = "0x"+color.substring(1);
    }
    else if (color.substring(0,2) == "0x")
    {
        textInput.maxChars = 8;
    }
    else
    {
        textInput.maxChars = 6;
        color = "0x"+color;
    }

    highlight.visible = false;
    isOverGrid = false;
    selectedColor = Number(color);

    dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));   
}
```

It looks like the RichEditableText is truncating the value before the change event has a chance to update the maxChars value. From RichEditableText:

```
if (maxChars != 0)
{
    var length1:int = text.length - delLen;
    var length2:int = textToInsert.length;
    // it is truncated from "#0000FF" to "#0000F" here
    if (length1 + length2 > maxChars)
        textToInsert = textToInsert.substr(0, maxChars - length1);
}
```

So it looks like in SwatchPanel the change event, textInput_changeHandler is too late to change the maxChars property to not truncate pasted values. Is there any recommendations on how to fix this?

**Full Example Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

<mx:ColorPicker id="colorPicker" 
                horizontalCenter="0"
                verticalCenter="0"
                paste="trace('pasted')" 
                valueCommit="colorPicker_valueCommitHandler(event)" 
       creationComplete="colorpicker1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"/>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
protected function colorpicker1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
    var textinput:ITextInput;

    if (colorPicker.dropdown==null) {
        var swatch:SwatchPanel = colorPicker.getDropdown();
        textinput = swatch.textInput;
    }
    else {
        textinput = colorPicker.getDropdown().textInput;
    }

    IEventDispatcher(textinput).addEventListener("paste", pasteincolorpicker);

    IEventDispatcher(textinput).addEventListener("change", pasteincolorpicker);
    IEventDispatcher(textinput).addEventListener("changing", pasteincolorpicker);
    IEventDispatcher(textinput).addEventListener("valueCommit", pasteincolorpicker);
}
private function pasteincolorpicker(event:Event):void
{
    trace("event.type: " + event.type);
    if (event.type=="changing") {
        event.currentTarget.maxChars = 7;
    }
    var text:String = "";
    if (event is TextOperationEvent) {
        text = TextOperationEvent(event).operation.textFlow.getText();
    }
    trace("pasting: " + text);
}


protected function colorPicker_valueCommitHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    trace("value commit: ");    
}

]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: Interesting question there. Just tried it out. The problem only happens when the text input has the max chars set to 6, which is the last else path in that change handler, try this out, delete the entire color text before pasting, and you can see the problem being reproduced I think. Put a breakpoint and check the color string being pasted. I will try to see if we can find a solution to this.

Comment: Is it possible for you to catch the paste keyboard event and modify the clipboard text before pasting it? Just thinking aloud.

Comment: The paste event is too late but I'll add the code I was using to work on this above.

Comment: @GurtejSingh I think that will work. The paste event is too late but the changing event seems to let me change the maxChars before paste. I think it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to occur when using FTE in mx components in your Flex project. Below is a extended ColorPicker that fixes the issue. This doesn't seem to work when FTE in mx components is not checked (tested on one project).

```
use namespace mx_internal;

public class ColorPicker extends mx.controls.ColorPicker
{
    public function ColorPicker()
    {
        super();
    }


    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();

        var swatch:SwatchPanel = getDropdown();
        if (!swatch.textInput.hasEventListener(FlexEvent.CHANGING)) {
            swatch.textInput.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CHANGING, changingEventHandler);
        }
    }

    protected function changingEventHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        // set it to max characters of 8
        // allow room for "123456", "#234567", "0x345678" before paste truncates it
        // change event handler in SwatchPanel will set it back to 8, 7 or 6 max chars
        if (event is TextOperationEvent) {
            dropdown.textInput.maxChars = 8;
            //text = TextOperationEvent(event).operation.textFlow.getText();
            //trace("changing to: " + text);
        }
    }
}
```